# XML FadeOut Animation not working

Tags: java, android, xml, animation

I have a generic FadeOut animation that is used on a lot of other things. I took out a button and switched it to a new button leaving the onClick the same. The only difference is position and src:Image. What I mean by not working is that it just goes to view gone and doesn't fadeout. it worked as intended with the other button but not this one

MainActivity

```
public void onPreferenceClose(View view){

    FadeOut = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this, R.anim.fade_out);
    FadeIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this, R.anim.fade_in);
    if(preferences.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE){

        preferences.startAnimation(FadeOut);
        preferences.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        preferences.clearAnimation();


        w_Toolbar.startAnimation(FadeIn);
        w_Toolbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        p_Web.setClickable(false);
    }
}
```

xml

```
<set
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fillBefore="true"
android:fillAfter="true"
android:duration="350">
<alpha
    android:fromAlpha="1.0"
    android:toAlpha="0.0"
    />
```

Comment: where is your XML code for animation

Comment: @ZaidMirza is uploaded

Answer (score 1):

your `Fadeout` animation is working but as you are setting the visibility (preferences) to `gone` it doesnt show animation ..because it makes it **Gone** first.. dont use setVisibility to Gone it isnt required for fadeout anim.. it will automatically do that for you ...or you can use listeners for your animation and at the end of animation make the view Gone

`

```
<alpha
    android:duration="1000"
    android:fromAlpha="1.0"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
    android:toAlpha="0.0" />
```

`

use this code for anim..

done forget to use `android:fillAfter="true" >` in set ...
`<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fillAfter="true" >`

Answer (score 0):

**remove this line**.

```
    preferences.clearAnimation();
```

your animation started and was cleared, that's why you cant see it

Comment: CleanAnimation was in use so i could still use the webview after, it worked but now i cant use the webview cause the layout is there just invisible now